# MySQL/SSRS Performance question - Involves adding a Dataset of 1-col/14-rows, lookup

Tags: mysql, reporting-services

I requested an SSRS report a while ago from a third party vendor that generates a PDF with data divided by trimesters for each user (you could end up with 60-100 users).

We asked for several conditions to be met and the programmer ended up with 13 datasets, 35 expressions, some of them included a "=code.store..." (that I have no idea what it means) and lookups.

The programmer didn't meet one of our requirements: to make sure that a row changes the name of the item to a hard coded generic value if the value is found within a department. E.g. "Asus ROG Zephyrus G14" belongs to the laptops department, then the value changes to "Laptop". It is only one department that has this condition.

When I asked for the reason, the programmer told me that it couldn't be done. That it can only check for fixed values and not the department itself, that he needs to hard code each item id to change the name.

So, I came up with this and presented it to the programmer:

**MySQL**

```
select C.intInventoryItem as InventoryValues from TblInventoryManagerItems inner join (

select intDepartment, intInventoryItem from 
TblInventoryManagerItemDepartmentLinks where intDepartment = @department) as C

on TblInventoryManagerItems.intInventoryItem = C.intInventoryItem

group by C.intInventoryItem
```

**Then on SSRS**

```
(Lookup(Fields!intInventoryID.Value,Fields!InventoryValues.Value,Fields!InventoryValues.Value,"Department") <> Nothing)
```

When I presented this working proof to the programmer (in a very polite, non-insulting manner, almost making myself look foolish in the email), he said that it would cause massive performance issues and if we need a solution like this, it would cost money and that it would take a month to deliver it.

Because I was already lied to in the 1st place, this second answer becomes very suspicious and we're still not getting what we requested originally.

The dataset is 1 column and 14 rows. Even though each line would check 14 rows, it still runs pretty fast and I perceive no difference in time from the original report. However, MySQL and SSRS are not my main programming languages, therefore I prefer to ask an expert in the matter.

TL;DR - How can I measure the execution time of 1 report vs another in SSRS? (something like time.clock() in Python); also, can adding 1 dataset of 1 column and 14 rows, then lookup cause massive performance issues?

Comment: This question is likely to get closed as it's not a specific programming question (SO rules). However, I would not expect a lookup like that to add a significant amount of time to processing, another option would be to add your lookup table to the database and do it there. The `=Code.store...` means the dev has added custom VB code to the report (check report properties to see the code). Finally, why not make a copy of the RDL, make the lookup changes yourself and see what happens. 13 datasets seems a lot but with no knowledge or your dataset it's subjective, maybe lots of parameters to fill?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did make a copy and it runs pretty much the same as the original. Also, thanks for clarifying the Code. meaning and the recommendation. Since this is not my main language, I truly needed an expert's advice. Sorry for the lack of details.

Comment: As for your final question, if you look in the SSRS database (ReportServer) then there is an executionlog (`ReportServer.dbo.executionlog`) table which holds stats such as data retrieval time, processing time (this is the one that will be affected by the lookup) and rendering time each time a report is executed. This could be used to do your comparsion although my feeling is that it will show there is very little performance drop by adding the lookup.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clean up the SQL.

```
select  C.intInventoryItem as InventoryValues
    from  ...
    group by  C.intInventoryItem
```

Perhaps you meant

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.intInventoryItem as InventoryValues
    from  ...
```

It seems that including `intDepartment` is unnecessary:

```
        SELECT  intDepartment, intInventoryItem
```

You can probably use a JOIN without the subquery.

Perhaps this would suffice?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT intInventoryItem
    FROM  TblInventoryManagerItems AS mi
    JOIN  TblInventoryManagerItemDepartmentLinks AS dl USING(intInventoryItem)
    WHERE  dl.intDepartment = @department
```

Indexes:

```
dl:  INDEX(intDepartment, intInventoryItem)
mi:  INDEX(intInventoryItem)
```

Consider shortening the table and column names.

Comment: Hi there,
Thank you for your input. Definitely adding a DISTINCT is better, to avoid duplicates. The result is the same in this case, as the table didn't have any duplicates, originally.
I tried to run the query, but I believe that I did something wrong, as I got the error msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3: Incorrect syntax near 'USING'.
I tried changing USING(intInventoryItem) to USING(dl.intInventoryItem), but it was the same result.

Comment: `USING(x)` is short for `ON mi.x = di.x`  Try that syntax